Number of chords to partition concentric circles to exclude area
Sorry for the poor title, but geometry is not my strong suit.
Nerd sniped myself with this problem while masking off circular vinyl negatives on the bottom of circular glasses for etching.
Is there a way to algorithmically derive the minimum number of chords (i.e. edges of pieces of tape) to partition the major of the concentric circles such all area of the major circle not contained in the minor is "covered"

On the trivial lower bound of things, if a shape is entirely contained within an inscribed triangle of the minor circle.
The number of chords is 3:

Where the problem gets complicated, and where I got stuck, is if the internal shape is not contained in the inscribed triangle of the minor circle.

I, by hand, came to a solution of 5 chords for the above, but have no way of proving that is the minimal number.
In reality the actual internal shape is a lot more complex (text and symbols) though I believe it can be simplified down to an n-gon by the extents of the letters.
Is there any existing literature that could provide some solutions?
I ask because I have over 100 stickers to apply and mask off and knowing where to put tape ahead of time would save me a few headaches
Feel free to recommend edits to help me explain the problem better, but looking forward to see what the community comes up with here to save me some tape :)

It seems to be the number of sides of the internal shape.
